# When will TeX Live 2013 ISO file be released?

Tags: texlive

In [this page](http://www.tug.org/texlive/), I couldn't understand the date for releasing TeX Live 2013 ISO file. So when will TeX Live 2013 ISO file be released?

Comment: July 1st is the planned date for the public release.

Comment: If one joins TUG now http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-dvd.html and pays the fees,  will then one get the 2013 DVD by snail mail sometime in early July? Will it install on Linux as well as windows?

Comment: @Nasser -- Early July seems a bit unrealistic (but I forget when I usually receive mine).  However, it will install on Linux.

Comment: The updating of packages should have been stopped on May 27 (actually some correction is still possible). Final testing will be carried on and if all goes well the master image will be sent for printing the DVD in a few days. So it seems that the team is on schedule for the planned release date. Early July for getting the DVD seems a bit optimistic (it depends on mail).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that web site says:

Plan for TeX Live 2013:
27mar: sources committed, builds begin.
8apr: tlnet (and TL'12) frozen, tlpretest starts, CTAN updates continue there.
27may: complete freeze for final build, no more updates, final doc tweaks, always more testing.
8jun: deliver final images for the TeX Collection DVD to manufacturing.
1jul: public release (also of MacTeX).
August?: delivery of DVDs to members.

istm that it says “public release” on 2013-07-01.  there’s no list of files to be released, so “obviously” the iso image will not be excluded, given that it’s a regular part of tl distribution.